# I am having trouble with this understanding this second derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

[image]
Here n = 1/r could somebody please explain to me how the second derivative of r with respect to t was calculated here

https://mypages.iit.edu/~smile/guests/Newton98B3.pdf

It is taken from page 16 of this pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You have the identity $\frac{dr}{dt} = -K \frac{dn}{d\theta}$. Differentiated again to find the second derivative.

Firstly, the constant $-K$ will stay the same, because $\frac{d}{dx}[c\cdot f(x)] = c \frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]$.

Secondly, use the chain rule on $\frac{dn}{d\theta}$ because we are differentiating with respect to $t$. The chain rule says the $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}$. In your example, $y=\frac{dn}{d\theta}$, $x=t$ and $u=\theta$. So $\frac{dn}{d\theta}$ will become $\frac{d^2n}{d\theta^2} \cdot \frac{d\theta}{dt}$ and altogether

$$ \frac{d^2r}{dt^2} = -K \frac{d^2n}{d\theta^2} \cdot \frac{d\theta}{dt} $$

Comment: Thankyou that makes a lot more sense now

Answer (score 1):

If $n=\frac{1}{r}$ you can replace $n$ and cancel $n^2$ so
$$ \frac{dr}{dt}=-K\frac{dn}{d\theta}$$

Now, I suppose $\theta$ depends on time, so by [chain rule](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-chain-2009-1.pdf) $\frac{df(g(t))}{dt}=\frac{df(g)}{dg}\frac{dg}{dt}$

$$\frac{d \frac{dr}{dt}}{dt}=-K \frac{d\frac{dn}{d\theta}}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$